# Error in SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Anybody use SharePoint Designer 2013 with SharePoint 2016?
When  open site SP 2016 in SPD 2013 and try to see list and libraries
I see that error:

**There are not items to show in this view**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.
In site was library with reports, that was created in SSRS 2014.
SPD display all list\libraries after deleted thih item from site content.

Answer (score 0):

On the only time I have every seen this is when the user that opened SPD didn't have correct permissions.

I use SPD13 with SP16 nearly every week without any issues.

What build of SP are you on?
What version of SPD are you using?